# How do I determine the new size for resize2fs?

Tags: partition, ext4, resize2fs

I want to shrink an ext4 filesystem to make room for a new partition and came across the `resize2fs` program. The command looks like this:

```
resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/ExistingExt4 $size
```

How should I determine `$size` if I want to substract exactly 15 GiB from the current ext4 filesystem? Can I use the output of `df` somehow?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should not use `df` because it shows the size as reported by the filesystem (in this case, ext4).

Use the `dumpe2fs -h /dev/mapper/ExistingExt4` command to find out the real size of the partition. The `-h` option makes `dumpe2fs` show super block info without a lot other unnecessary details. From the output, you need the **block count** and **block size**.

```
...  
Block count:              19506168  
Reserved block count:     975308  
Free blocks:              13750966  
Free inodes:              4263842  
First block:              0  
Block size:               4096  
...
```

Multiplicating these values will give the partition size in **bytes**.

The above numbers happen to be a perfect multiple of 1024, so we can calculate the result in KiB:

```
$ python -c 'print 19506168.0 * 4096 / 1024'  # python2
$ python -c 'print(19506168.0 * 4096 / 1024)' # python3
78024672.0
```

Since you want to shrink the partition by 15 GiB (which is 15 MiB times 1 KiB):

```
$ python -c 'print 19506168.0 * 4096 / 1024  -  15 * 1024 * 1024'   #python2
$ python -c 'print(19506168.0 * 4096 / 1024  -  15 * 1024 * 1024)'  #python3
62296032.0
```

As `resize2fs` accepts several kinds of suffixes, one of them being `K` for "1024 bytes", the command for shrinking the partition to 62296032 KiB becomes:

```
resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/ExistingExt4 62296032K
```

Without unit, the number will be interpreted as a multiple of the filesystem's blocksize (4096 in this case). See [man resize2fs(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/resize2fs.8.html)

Comment: man resize2fs: Optionally, the size parameter may be suffixed
by one of the following the units designators: 's', 'K', 'M', or 'G', for  512
byte  sectors,  kilobytes, megabytes, or gigabytes, respectively. May be simpler than doing block calculations.

Comment: Aren't you missing a `k` at `resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/ExistingExt4 62296032` ?

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez You are right, a capital `K` was missing. Without this letter, resize2fs should complain in my case as the size is larger than the actual disk.

Comment: `dumpe2fs` doesn't report the partition size; it really reports the size of the file system. (Which is good, because it's probably what you want.)