# How can I shrink a LUKS partition, what does `cryptsetup resize` do?

Tags: partition, encryption, ext4, luks, cryptsetup

I am in progress of resizing a LUKS encrypted partition that contains a single ext4 filesystem (no LVM or something). The [cryptsetup FAQ](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) recommends to remove the old partition and recreate it, but that sounds like wasting a lot time. Therefore I want to proceeed by manually, carefully resizing the partition.

So far, I think that I need to do:

1. **Create an (encrypted) backup of the filesystem. Important! You won't be the first to lose your data while performing the following tasks.**
2. Unmount the existing ext4 filesystem (e.g. by booting into a Live CD). If booting from a Live CD, mount the encrypted partition using `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdXY ExistingExt4`
3. [Resize the existing ext4 filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41088/8250).
4. `cryptsetup resize /dev/mapper/ExistingExt4 -b $SECTORS`
5. Close/ "unmount" the LUKS partition using `cryptsetup luksClose ExistingExt4`
6. Shrink the partition size.

**Are the above steps correct?**

In step 4, **what should I choose for `$SECTORS`? Is this step even necessary?** The `cryptsetup` manual page is not really descriptive on the `resize` option:

```
resize <name>
    resizes an active mapping <name>.
    If --size (in sectors) is not specified, the size of the underlying
    block device is used.
```

Finally, if I shrink the ext4 partition by 15 GiB, can I safely assume that 15 GiB can be removed from the existing partition using `parted`? If yes, how to do so? My disk is GPT partitioned, if that matters.

Comment: I've always wondered about the resize option on cryptsetup as well. Even the cryptsetup FAQ says: "2.15 Can I resize a dm-crypt or LUKS partition? Yes, you can, as neither dm-crypt nor LUKS stores partition size." So why does it have a resize option if it has nothing to do with partition size...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After backing up (step 1) and unmounting (between 2 and 3), run `fsck` to ensure that the filesystem is healthy:

```
e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/ExistingExt4
```

Other than that, the steps are OK.

### Purpose of the `cryptsetup resize` command

> what should I choose for $SECTORS? Is this step even necessary?

<del>This step is necessary, otherwise the partition would still show up at the old side. This is confirmed with Nautilus, even after resizing with `resize2fs`, the LUKS partition showed up as the old size. After running `cryptsetup resize`, the correct number is shown.</del> **This step is not necessary.** It only affects the current size status as shown in the file browser. After changing the size and closing/opening the partition again, the number is restored. So, when closing the LUKS partition as shown later will make this obsolete.

`$SECTORS` can be determined by looking at the output of `cryptsetup status ExistingExt4`:

```
    /dev/mapper/ExistingExt4 is active.
      type:    LUKS1
      cipher:  aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
      keysize: 256 bits
      device:  /dev/sda2
      sector size:  512
      offset:  2056 sectors
      size:    156049348 sectors
      mode:    read/write
```

(As of [cryptsetup 2.0.0 (December 2017)](https://www.saout.de/pipermail/dm-crypt/2017-December/005771.html), the sector size may be larger than 512 bytes: see the [`cryptsetup(8)` manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cryptsetup.8.html) and the `--sector-size` option.)

Thus, to subtract 15 GiB, use a sector size of `156049348  -  15 * 1024 * 1024 * 2 = 124592068`:

```
cryptsetup resize ExistingExt4 -b 124592068
```

### Resizing the partition with `parted`

As for resizing the partition, `parted` works fine with GPT partitions. The `resize` command does not work however, as a workaround (or solution), remove the partition information and create a new partition as inspired by http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8721017#post8721017:

```
# cryptsetup luksClose ExistingExt4
# parted /dev/sda2
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) unit s
(parted) p
Model: ATA INTEL SSDSA2CW08 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 156301488s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start    End         Size        File system  Name    Flags
 1      34s      2082s       2049s                    Boot    bios_grub
 3      2083s    250034s     247952s     ext2         RootBoot
 2      250035s  156301438s  156051404s               Everything
```

As 15 GiB has to be shaved off, the new end becomes `156301438 - 15 * 1024 * 1024 * 2 = 124844158`. Since I want to change partition 2, I first have to remove it and then recreate it with the label "Everything" (this could be changed if you like). **Note**: this disk has a GPT layout. For MBR, you should replace `Everything` by `primary` or `extended` (untested, resizing a partition on MBR has **not** been tested and is **not** recommended because it is untested).

**WARNING**: the following commands has [destroyed data](http://www.saout.de/pipermail/dm-crypt/2013-September/003521.html). Do not copy it without understanding what is happening. The sector dimensions **must** be changed, otherwise you **WILL** destroy your partition(s). I am in no way responsible for your stupidness, **BACKUP BACKUP BACKUP** your data to a **second** storage medium before risking your data.

```
(parted) rm 2
(parted) mkpart Everything 250035s 124844158s
Warning: The resulting partition is not properly aligned for best performance.
Ignore/Cancel? ignore
(parted) p
Model: ATA INTEL SSDSA2CW08 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 156301488s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start    End         Size        File system  Name    Flags
 1      34s      2082s       2049s                    Boot    bios_grub
 3      2083s    250034s     247952s     ext2         RootBoot
 2      250035s  124844158s  124594124s               Everything
(parted) quit
```

In the above `parted` example, my sectors are not aligned which is a mistake from an earlier installation, do not pay too much attention to it.

That is it! You can use `cryptsetup status` and `file -Ls /dev/...` to verify that everything is OK and then reboot.

Comment: I strongly advise against using this solution without full backup, as it is highly likely to go wrong. But if you have a full backup, creating a new partition is a lot easier.

Comment: Let me guess, a human did this? Anyway I have now clearly emphasized that a backup should be performed before playing with this. I thought it was obvious that a backup has to be performed before doing such this manually... even then how could someone mess this up given the clear instructions and ways to verify?

Comment: Do you also have a source for the failure you mentioned? Everyone can make a claim that the provided information is incorrect, but I would like to verify it. It may be helpful for other users in the future...

Comment: Arno was talking of this post on the mailing list: http://www.saout.de/pipermail/dm-crypt/2013-September/003521.html

Comment: Instead of `rm 2` and `mkpart [part-type] [start] [end]`, one can also use `resizepart 2 [end]` to resize a partition without changing the name or start offset.

Comment: @RobW There was an older version where that command did not exist or had a bug with interpreting relative values. If it works for you now, great!

Answer (score 8):

Note that [KDE Partition Manager 2.2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Partition_Manager) can do those steps and resizing LUKS partitions works nicely.

Comment: [KDE Partition Manager 4 also supports resizing LUKS2 volumes](https://old.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/agfi9y/kde_partition_manager_4_beta/). This is [not supported by GParted](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gparted/-/issues/59), as of late 2020.

Comment: With `gparted` I always had trouble, KDE app worked fine.

Comment: To install [KDE Partition Manager](https://github.com/KDE/partitionmanager) on Ubuntu: `sudo apt install partitionmanager`