# How can I resize my encrypted root and home partitions, to give root more space?

Tags: fedora, partition, hard-disk, encryption, root-filesystem

I need to enlarge my / (root) partition, I have a lot of space on my /home partition so how can I do this? The drive is encrypted with LUKS.

My system is Fedora 20.

I have another thread [here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/47803/help-root-partion-is-full-how-do-i-rectify/) which mentions system-config-lvm but this seems to be a outdated tool as it is not installed or in the repositories.
Gparted doesn't work as it doesn't support LUKS encryption.

Here is:

```
~]$ sudo fdisk -l 

Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7AE6E531-9898-4C7C-8C35-41B4FDB9374A

Device           Start          End   Size Type
/dev/sda1         2048       411647   200M EFI System
/dev/sda2       411648      1435647   500M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3      1435648    976773119 465.1G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/mapper/luks-e69b0b4c-a8e0-425f-988d-8c635729503b: 465.1 GiB, 499370688512 bytes, 975333376 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/fedora_hostname-swap: 3.8 GiB, 4043309056 bytes, 7897088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/fedora_hostname-root: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/luks-b7af1bce-82c4-4921-aac1-bce701e30256: 50 GiB, 53684994048 bytes, 104853504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/fedora_hostname-home: 411.3 GiB, 441639239680 bytes, 862576640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Here is:

```
~]$ df -h
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-3                         50G   45G  2.0G  96% /
devtmpfs                         1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                            1.9G   80K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            1.9G  9.0M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                            1.9G   20K  1.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda2                        477M  131M  317M  30% /boot
/dev/sda1                        200M  9.6M  191M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/fedora_hostname-home  405G  202G  183G  53% /home
```

Here is:

```
]$ sudo lvdisplay        
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/fedora_hostname/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                fedora_hostname
  LV UUID                qQQRVR-toXX-J0M7-lTH5-d8Lr-AUq3-EHJ6A4
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time hostname.lan, 2014-03-24 15:51:10 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                3.77 GiB
  Current LE             964
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/fedora_hostname/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                fedora_hostname
  LV UUID                In2lRz-16ul-VhH5-SQOE-yqlt-tMB3-5JM7ea
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time hostname.lan, 2014-03-24 15:51:10 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                411.31 GiB
  Current LE             105295
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:4

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/fedora_hostname/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                fedora_hostname
  LV UUID                bBWzcC-nhhd-s8km-MMGi-uGQ0-8yBv-HClQgp
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time hostname.lan, 2014-03-24 15:51:16 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                50.00 GiB
  Current LE             12800
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2
```

Comment: this may be similar http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41091/how-can-i-shrink-a-luks-partition-what-does-cryptsetup-resize-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in [this](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/47803/how-can-i-resize-root-and-home-partitions-on-a-encrypted-system-to-give-root-more-space/) thread....

Exerpt:

Therefore, the steps would be like this:

1. Shrink the /home "filesystem". (e.g. if it is ext4, it should be
   resized using resize2fs).
2. Shrink the /home LVM partition (/dev/mapper/fedora_hostname-home)
   size so that it completely includes /home shrinked filesystem using
   lvreduce
3. If the shrinked filesystem is smaller than /home LVM partition, you
   can resize the filesystem again to fill LVM logical volume
   completely. I usually use this method so that I don't need to
   calculate sizes accurately! :P

(After each of the above steps, you can mount /home to see if it mounts correctly, and data is there. If not (for example because of wrong parameters), you can revert that problematic step).

The steps for enlarging / partition would be like this:

1. Enlarge / LVM partition (/dev/mapper/fedora_hostname-root) to fill the free space (using lvextend)
2. Enlarge / LUKS partition to fill /dev/mapper/fedora_hostname-root
   LVM partition (using cryptsetup resize)
3. Enlarge / filesystem to fill / LUKS partition (e.g. using resize2fs
   if ext2/3/4)