# Physical volumes, logical volumes, superblocks gone... how to boot?

Tags: luks, lvm, superblock

A story fairly similar to [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33284/recovering-ext4-superblocks/41946#41946) happened to me yesterday.

*Update:*
My only hard drive `/dev/sda` was originally partitioned this way:

```
Device     Boot   Start        End     Blocks  Id  System
/dev/sda1  *       2048    1026047     512000  83   Linux
/dev/sda2       1026048  976773119  487873536  83   Linux
```

`/dev/sda1` is the `/boot` partition, it is not encrypted. The `/dev/sda2` partition was originally a LUKS partition containing the volume group `fedora_pedro`, which itself contained the following logical volumes:

```
/dev/mapper/fedora_pedro-root
/dev/mapper/fedora_pedro-home
/dev/mapper/fedora_pedro-swap
```

I was on a live disk, just about to shrink the `/dev/sda2` partition following [those steps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41091/how-can-i-shrink-a-luks-partition-what-does-cryptsetup-resize-do) when I abruptly had to stop and unplug my computer. I just had mounted the partition using

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda2 fedora_pedro
```

and had a look around the place (first time I was playing with LVM & LUKS), mounting and unmounting the different logical volumes (swap, root, home), when I had to hastily shut the terminal down without closing the LUKS partition (`exit`; `exit`). Not really paying attention, I withdrew the live CD before the end of the shutdown procedure and turned the laptop off pressing the power button.

When I started the computer a few hours later, the boot hung at "Reached Target Basic System"; the only hint I got from booting from the hard drive in rescue mode was

```
dracut-initqueue [...] unit file of systemd-cryptsetup@luksMYUUID changed on disk
```

Using a rescue disk, I opened the drive (`cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda2 fedora_pedro`) and I inquired the status of the partition using `e2fsck`, which returned a pretty

```
fsck.ext4: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda2
```

`pvdisplay` returned that all PE were free (so the volume was shown as virtually empty), and `vgscan` shared that opinion, too, mentioning that my volume group did not contain any logical volume. `lvdisplay` returned nothing.

I had not resized anything yet, so I was very puzzled by the problem.

```
testdisk /dev/mapper/fedora_pedro
```

showed the right volumes (swap, root and home) and allowed access to all data on the system, so I chose to `Write partition to the disk`, hoping that I could see them after rebooting. That did not happen however, although `fdisk -l /dev/mapper/fedora_pedro` now returns

```
Disk /dev/mapper/fedora_pedro: 465.3 GiB, 49958403712 bytes, 975742976 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0000000

Device                      Boot     Start        End     Blocks  Id  System
/dev/mapper/fedora_pedro1  *         2048    8161279    4079616  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/mapper/fedora_pedro2         8161280  870885375  431362048  82  Linux
/dev/mapper/fedora_pedro3       870885376  975742975   52428800  82  Linux
```

I'm still not able to mount the volumes individually as I was able to unmount them when everything was O.K.. In fact, I cannot find them in `/dev/mapper`.
Additionally, since I copied the table to the disk, that I cannot see the physical volumes anymore, let alone the groups and the logical volumes (`pvscan`, `vgscan` & `lvscan` commands return nothing). But I remain confident and I am sure that the solution to this problem is not so far fetched:

- Maybe renaming the volume entries in the partition table to match the original ones in the grub. <-- Unlikely
- <s>Maybe find a backup and restore the system using `vgcfgrestore` or equivalent. <-- Possible</s> See below
- Maybe rewrite the superblocks on the disk using `mke2fs -S`, as was proposed in the story I mentioned at the beginning. `testdisk` is positive about the size of the blocks: 4096. <-- Risky

But all those solutions (and the other ones you might propose) go beyond my limited knowledge of the logical volume system, as the reading may have disclosed already. I would like to know which procedure would be suitable to boot again properly.

*News from the front*

Again, I accessed my old system using `testdisk`. As mentioned before, the partitions are fine and I had a peek at my old file system, especially `/etc` to see if I could fetch some valuable information to restore. The longer this game goes on, the more I have the feeling that it is just a matter of labeling. I copied `/etc/lvm` to the live Documents file and tried to use it as a backup file for `vgcfgrestore`, but it returned a poor

```
Couldn't find device with uuid cZ83jX-WXkk-tNG4-ulGT-sAqq-HlKq-Omtqc8.
PV unknown device missing from cache
Format-specific setup for unknown device failed
Restore failed.
```

In fact, `blkid` does not return any uuid similar to that. What is more thrilling (and probably my own deed), is the fact that `blkid` returns this for my Ext4 file system:

```
/dev/sda1: "9f2a5417-dce6-45c1-8d93-1ee753e5c75c" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0006282d-01"
/dev/sda2: "a33beb04-1147-446e-8f3b-7ff9d6bc226b" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="0006282d-02"
[...]
/dev/mapper/fedora_pedro: PTTYPE="dos"
```

I think I made a mistake with `Write partition to disk` in `testdisk`, as the uuid of my current `fedora_pedro` does in no way match with the one of the original one. In fact, `fedora_pedro` has no uuid. Is it possible to attribute to this volume all the specifications of the previous, working unit: uuid, logical partitioning, ... If yes, how?

*Getting closer?*

`vgchange -ay fedora_pedro` returns

```
Volume group "fedora_pedro" not found
Skipping volume group fedora_pedro
```

Even though I use the same volume group name as the original one, mentioned in `/etc/lvm/backup/` or `/etc/lvm/archive`. `vgdisplay` says exactly the same.

What's interesting is the output of `lvmdiskscan`

```
/dev/mapper/live-rw        [   4.00 GiB]
/dev/sda1                  [ 500.00 MiB]
/dev/mapper/live-base      [   4.00 GiB]
/dev/loop2                 [ 886.75 MiB]
/dev/sda2                  [ 465.27 GiB]
/dev/mapper/live-osimg-min [   4.00 GiB]
/dev/mapper/loop3          [   4.00 GiB]
/dev/mapper/fedora_pedro   [ 465.27 GiB] LVM physical volume
/dev/loop4                 [ 512.00 MiB]
3 disks
5 partitions
1 LVM physical volume whole disk
0 LVM physical volume
```

If I understand it correctly, someone knows that there is a physical volume out there. But it does not want to show it.

```
$ pvdisplay fedora_pedro
Failed to read physical volume "fedora_pedro"

$ pvdisplay /dev/mapper/fedora_pedro
No physical volume found in lvmetad cache for /dev/mapper/fedora_pedro
Failed to read physical volume "/dev/mapper/fedora_pedro"

$ pvdisplay /home/liveuser/Documents/etc/lvm/archive/fedora_pedro_00000-1031984471.vg
Failed to read physical volume "/home/liveuser/Documents/etc/lvm/archive/fedora_pedro_00000-1031984471.vg"
```

I'm not sure how to go further. I did `lvmdump -m` and had a look at the dmsetup_ls_tree, dmsetup_table, dmsetup_status and dmsetup_info. dmsetup_info returns the following UUID for fedora_pedro

```
Name         Maj Min Stat Open Targ Event UUID
fedora_pedro 253   3 L--w    0    1     0 CRYPT-LUKS1-a33beb04-1147-446e-8f3b-7ff9d6bc226b-fedora_pedro
```

This is the same UUID as the one returned by `blkid` for `/dev/sda2`. It is also the same as what I find at line 26 of `/home/liveuser/Documents/etc/lvm/archive/fedora_pedro_00000-1031984471.vg`

```
[...]
pv0 {
       id = "cZ83jX-WXkk-tNG4-ulGT-sAqq-HlKq-Omtqc8"
       device = "/dev/mapper/luks-a33beb04-1147-446e-8f3b-7ff9d6bc226b" # Hint only
[...]
```

and in the `grub.cfg` file on `/dev/sda1`.

As I wrote in the list above, will try to match the id's and UUID together, but I think the glitch is somewhere else.

Comment: After having read that several times I am still not sure what your disk looked like. What layer is encrypted, the whole disk, a single partition, an LV? What is the PV? "so I chose to copy the table to the disk" - Does that mean you had a partition table **within** a LUKS volume / disk and have copied that to the disk itself? That would have destroyed the LUKS header.

Comment: Run the command `vgchange -ay fedora_hostname`. After that what is the output of `vgdisplay -v fedora_hostname`?

Comment: I think it's not a problem that the `sda2` UUID is reused in DM device names. Probably means: "This is the decrypted version of $UUID". That it is detected as PV but cannot be scanned may mean that the LVM metadata has been destroyed. If the LVs have been created without fragmentation then it should be possible to recreate them (with the correct size) to get access to the data. I am not familiar with `testdisk` but it should show you where the LVs are. You need to know their size and must (re)create them in the right order. IMHO this cannot cause (more) damage.

Answer (score 3):

By some mystery I had wiped the volume group and the physical volume in it. It was just a matter of [recovering them using the metadata](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/mdatarecover.html) I could back-up using `testdisk`. I copied the original `/etc/lvm` folder on the Desktop of the live user, then

```
$ pvcreate --uuid "cZ83jX-WXkk-tNG4-ulGT-sAqq-HlKq-Omtqc8" \
--restorefile /home/liveuser/Desktop/etc/lvm/archive/VG.vg /dev/sda2
  Physical volume "/dev/sda2" successfully created

$ vgcfgrestore VG
  Restored volume group VG

$ lvchange -ay /dev/VG/home /dev/VG/root /dev/VG/swap

$ lvs -a -o +devices
```

After that, `vgdisplay -v fedora_pedro` returned consistent output, mentioning the original logical and physical volumes, which I was allowed to mount and explore. A couple of minutes later, though, I unfortunately wiped the header of the luks container trying to write those changes to the disk. So all was done in vain...

Comment: As long as the system is running you can get the necessary data from `dmsetup --showkeys table fedora_pedro`.