# Live resize of root partition in case of "LUKS on LVM"

Tags: linux, lvm, ext4, luks

Having read about the pros and cons of "LUKS on LVM" vs "LVM on LUKS" I came to the conclusion that "LUKS on LVM" does not provide live resize. But why? And is this even true as of todays implementations?

For the context this is what I have in my /etc/crypttab:

```
decrypted_root  /dev/vg_ubuntu/LV_crypted_root none luks
```

This is my /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/mapper/decrypted_root   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Here is what I did:

```
lvextend -L +10G /dev/vg_ubuntu/LV_crypted_root
cryptsetup resize decrypted_root
resize2fs /dev/mapper/decrypted_root
```

And now my overall question: What could possibly go wrong with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extend a LUKS encrypted partition to fill disk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320957/extend-a-luks-encrypted-partition-to-fill-disk) as extending is not the problem: [shrinking is](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41091/how-can-i-shrink-a-luks-partition-what-does-cryptsetup-resize-do) as you need to unencrypt everything first.

Comment: Growing should work exactly the way you describe, so it's unclear how to help. Any error messages to go with that? Verify the size of the block devices with `blockdev --getsize64` or similar?