# How to calculate correct partition size when shrinking filesystem with resize2fs

Tags: filesystems, resize2fs

After shrinking a read only filesystem with resize2fs on GNU/Linux, how do i determine the correct partition entry for the shrunken filesystem?

Initial partition scheme of remote host:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1,8 TiB, 1999844147200 bytes, 3905945600 sectors
Disk model: xxx       
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf79ea8df

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048     487423     485376  237M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2           487424 3841943551 3841456128  1,8T 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       3841943552 3883886591   41943040   20G 83 Linux

Command (m for help):
```

Issuing resize command:

```
[root@home ~]# resize2fs /dev/sda2 200G
resize2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/sda2 to 52428800 (4k) blocks.
The filesystem on /dev/sda2 is now 52428800 (4k) blocks long.
```

When recreating the partition entry for /dev/sda2 with 487424 as start sector, and a size of 8 times 52428800 * 512 bytes blocks, does the created partition really cover the whole shrunken filesystem and how can that be proven ?

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1,8 TiB, 1999844147200 bytes, 3905945600 sectors
Disk model: xxx       
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf79ea8df

Device     Boot      Start        End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048     487423    485376  237M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2           487424  419917824 419430401  200G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       3841943552 3883886591  41943040   20G 83 Linux

Command (m for help):
```

Comment: Empirically, the size of a partition seems to be equal to or greater than "Block count" * "Block size" as reported by `dumpe2fs -h`. This is also the method used in the answer to this other [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41088/315749) (you may even flag your question as a duplicate of that one if you feel yours is answered). Though I couldn't find any reference for the assertion that "Block count" represents the total size of the file system.

Comment: I thought of recognizing the last block of the filesystem on the last block covered by the partition as a way to be sure it fits - but how do i recognize the last block ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the other question does not have any answers providing information about how to calculate an related correct partition entry. Are there any alignment issues ? Does a partition entry provide some extra space for filesystem meta data ? Or is the correct partition size always exactly the filesystem size, regardless of alignment and other unknown factors?